# Fleshcrafting in nWoD

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, conversion, vampire-the-requiem

I have had some people express interest in recreating the Tzimisce in my VtR game. I have far more experience with nWoD then old, and I have found no rules that attempt to tackle fleshcrafting, although the option seems to be possible.

Does anyone have a conversion of Fleshcrafting from oWoD to nWoD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find an nWoD conversion of Vicissitude in the **[Vampire Translation Guide](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=86202)**, and there's a bloodline called the Carnival in **Bloodlines: The Legendary** that has a flesh-warping Discipline called The Show.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mekhet clanbook, there is a bloodline called the Norvegi that uses a discipline called Bloodworking.  It's not the same thing, but it shares some aspects and is better suited to the nWoD, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the Centimani in [Promethean](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/12532/Promethean-The-Created). They are not vampires, but they have some pretty cool ability to transform themselves using Flux. A Centimani would also have the ability to turn corpses into Pandorans, which can be all sorts of weird and inhuman. One of the creep factors I felt about the Tzimisce and their fleshcrafting was their ability to do it to other things. I haven't found that with the new vampire alternatives.

Of course if they're looking to *play* a Tzimisce rather than have them as villains... this may not be the best route.

From [Mortal Remains](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/129193/Hunter-Mortal-Remains) p20

> **Centimani**
>
> Within the already small subset of beings called Prometheans is an even less numerous category — the Centimani. These
>   so-called Freaks revel in their inhuman appearances and attitude,
>   and reshape their bodies in terrifying ways. Many have additional
>   body parts — a second set of arms jutting out from the rib cage,
>   an eyeball in the center of a palm, a face sprouting from the belly
>   or back. Centimani can sometimes change shape, turning into a
>   puddle of mobile blood or a horrific, canine-esque monster.
>
> Other Prometheans seem to fear these creatures. They do not
>   follow the Pilgrimage — they have no regard for human beings and
>   have no desire to become one. They often travel with broods of
>   monsters, hideous, misshapen things that feed on the flesh of other
>   Prometheans. What, if anything, the Centimani have in common
>   with each other, and what their overriding goals are remain a mystery to the compacts and conspiracies. Whatever the truth, these
>   monsters are the Created without even the veneer of humanity. This
>   makes them easier to identify, but by no means easier to kill.

The best resource on them will be [Pandora's Book](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/23079/Pandoras-Book)

Answer (score 0):

**Belial's Brood** is pure nWoD not a translation, they have some fleshcrafting, like abilities, are vampires, and are basically pure evil, everything I love about the Tzimsce

[Covenant book](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/24480/Belials-Brood) p134

> Sarx is easily the most primal and visceral aspect of the
>   Trinity. The sarx is the flesh, purely and simply, and it
>   will be neither denied nor cast aside. The vampire cults
>   of the sarx believe in the importance of the material in
>   a material world, and the powers they manifest tend to
>   focus heavily on the strengthening and manipulation
>   thereof. At their most powerful, these Investments can
>   effect drastic and often monstrous changes to flesh both
>   alive and undead.

Here's an example power

> Flesh Spider
>
> The Forsworn often acknowledge that the spirit is
>   stronger than the flesh, but the flesh is a powerful tool
>   when put firmly under the yoke of the Beast. Just as the
>   Adversary’s unholy power allows a vampire’s corpse to
>   move and imitate life, so can this power animate flesh
>   and bone that has become separated from the whole.
>   Hands and limbs can be made to writhe and move at
>   the vampire’s whim, so long as they stay within his line
>   of sight. While separated, these portions can move on
>   their own, following the directions of the Forsworn that
>   detached them.
>   Prerequisites: Warp Corpse
>
> Success: The vampire’s limb or appendage is detached
>   and animated. Detached limbs have Health levels equivalent to their Size, a Defense of 1, a Strength of 1 and a
>   Speed of 8. This removal has no effect on the Forsworn’s
>   overall Health levels. A detached head can move on its
>   own, but leaves the vampire’s body helpless. Detached

and another that gives you an armor bonus...

> Unfeeling Skin
>
> One of the first sarx powers learned by many Forsworn
>   imparts the uncaring nature of the Beast onto the
>   vampire’s flesh. With barely a moment’s thought, the
>   Forsworn’s flesh becomes bruised and livid, as the Beast
>   inures his skin to the dangers of the outside world.

Sadly they have no mention as of yet in nWoD 2.0, except on the blog to say they still exist.